# Blazor javascript load not working in sometimes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I called javascript function named 'robotDisplayer.initRobot' in **OnAfterRenderAsync** but it not worked.

The error message is
**Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'robotDisplayer.initRobot' ('robotDisplayer' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'robotDisplayer.initRobot' ('robotDisplayer' was undefined).**

So I gave 1.5sec in **OnAfterRenderAsync**. After 1.5sec, I called javascript function('InitRobotJS') and It worked well

Working codes are below

======== C# code ========

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await lazyInitRobot();
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

async Task lazyInitRobot()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    while (true)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - now).TotalSeconds >= 1.5)
            break;
    }
    await InitRobotJS();
}

async Task InitRobotJS()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("robotDisplayer.initRobot");
}
```

======== javascript code ========

```
//File name : robot_render.js


function initRobot() {
...
}

window.robotDisplayer = {
    initRobot: () => { initRobot(); },
};
```

======== _Host.cshtml ========

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/robot_render.js"></script>
```

If I remove timer (1.5 sec), the error is occurred all time.
Is there time issue to load javascript?

Comment: My guess is that the script tag ```<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>``` is above your ```<script type="module" src="~/js/robot_render.js"></script>```? If so, the blazor framework is not only loaded but also executed before, so there is a fairly good chance that ```OnAfterRenderAsync``` will be executed by the server before the browser has even loaded your custom script. If you add the artificial delay, you give the browser enough time to load the script (adding it to the window namespace),

Comment: @Justthebenno Thank you for your explanation. I placed `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` above `<script type="module" src="~/js/robot_render.js"></script>` however it was not worked :(..

Comment: I'll take some time on the weekend trying to find a solution. Can you briefly describe your component tree and what component caused this issue? Like PageA-->TableComponent-->CellComponent etc?

Comment: @Justthebenno I really appreciate your help. The problem component is <div> which render 3D object. The <div> component's tree is just pageA -> <div> that's all. I'm using 'threejs' which is javascript library to render 3D objects. **robot_render** has render functions when page is initialized.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but I couldn't. It worked like expected. I still think it has something to do with the sequence of execution. Could you add two logging statements to the js file. Something like ```console.log("robot_render.js loading...");``` at the start and ```console.log("robot_render.js loaded.");``` at the end? I'm curious to see if your error happens in between or after ```loaded```.

Comment: @Justthebenno I tried you said thing. Since calling the function robotDisplayer.initRobot failed, console.log cannot be excute. I had to set the delay time around 2-3 seconds so it works fine.